# Simplygon cloud api authentication

Tags: api, authentication, cloud, simplygon

I can't seem to get past the authentication for the simplygon cloud api authentication. Response is:

`{
    "message": "Authorization has been denied for this request."
}`

I'm trying to get all assets via uri `GET /api/v1/assets`.

Trying to follow the instructions from https://simplygonclouddoc.simplygon.com/. I have my header with key `Authentication` and value `Basic {API_KEY}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh the key I was given by the Simplygon Cloud instance needed to be base64 encoded